# ""Significant" difference in an experimental test under two different conditions

Tags: statistical-significance

This seems a simple question, but I am way too dusty on statistics, so any help will be really appreciated.

Ok, I have one blood sample.

Then, I do a measurement (Aspect Ratio, vertical axis) at different stress levels (horiz. axis). However, I do the measurement under two different viscosity (red and brown in the image).
Now, I need to know if the results in **Red** is significantly different than results in **Brown**.

Stress and viscosities are independent variables, while aspect ratio is the dependent variable.

Note that every single point in the plot is a single measurement.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps an ANCOVA model

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially want is to conduct a 2D t-test. You may refer to this paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2532625.pdf) for more details.

If you just want to do some simple tests, I would suggest you conduct two separate t-tests, one for stress, the other for aspect ratio.

Comment: Why do I have to do a separate test for stress.  Stress and viscosities are both independent variables and aspect ratio is dependent.

Comment: You don't need to do it for stress. My suggestion is for general cases.